# How to create a checkout session from order in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, onepage-checkout

I have created an order from the backend, now I want to let the user to make the payment for that order using regular check process.

So is there any way of connecting that order to a checkout session so the user can continue with paying for the order which created from admin, without duplicating or creating a new order.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using REST API calls and Magento admin authorization tokens. Magento does allow admin user to create a cart on behalf of a customer.

"For all admin requests, you must provide an admin authorization token in the call’s authorization header."

This tutorial will give you a good lead:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/order-tutorial/order-intro.html